# Image processing library in asp.net (using C#) without flash

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, dll

I have the following requirement wherein I have to implement a paint brush kind of feature in a asp.net web application. Basically it should support resizing, drawing lines, squares, etc and a whole lot of features like a paint brush. I was googling out image processing libraries in internet. 
I found some - but the problem is most of them is with flash. I was looking for some option without flash since the application should run on a ipad also.

Can you people suggest some good image processing libraries which I can use in my asp.net (using C#) application.?

I have done good enough research regarding them. I do not have much time to download the trial versions and try each and every library. So I need the help of you all to suggest me something based on experience.

Comment: Yes - That should be fine. I am assuming Ipad and Iphone browsers support HTML5 !

Answer (score 0):

For the Image Resizing and cropping you can use [Image Resizer](http://imageresizing.net/) and for `drawing lines, squares, etc` you should use [HTML5 Canvus](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp).

There are a lot of [good libraries](http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=141) and [tutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/) for HTML5 Canvus.

Its easy to use and is available at [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer).

```
var settings = new ResizeSettings {
  MaxWidth = thumbnailSize,
  MaxHeight = thumbnailSize,
  Format = "jpg"
};
settings.Add("quality", quality.ToString());
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(inStream, outStream, settings);
resized = outStream.ToArray();
```

You can install it using Nuget

> PM> Install-Package ImageResizer

Answer (score 0):

you can use AForge.NET, a C# framework, here is code project link :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16859/AForge-NET-open-source-framework